# Symfony4 - Can't Autowire Service

Tags: php, symfony, service, dependency-injection, controller

It's the first time I try to autowire a service in symfony4, as symfony4 is new i'm never sure if the anwser I find online is working or is outdated..

In my services.yaml:

```
services:

   [...]

    smugmug_controller:
        class: App\Controller\SmugmugController
        arguments:
            - '@smugmug_service'

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
    smugmug_service:
        class: App\Services\SmugmugService
        arguments:
            $consumerKey: "%smugmug.consumer_key%"
            $consumerSecret: "%smugmug.consumer_secret%"
            $oauthToken: "%smugmug.oauth_token%"
            $oauthTokenSecret: "%smugmug.oauth_token_secret%"
            $allowedRootId: "%smugmug.allowed_root_id%"
```

In my Smugmug Service:

```
class SmugmugService 
{
    private $consumerKey;
    private $consumerSecret;
    private $oauthToken;
    private $oauthTokenSecret;
    private $allowedRootId;
    private $galleryNameFromDropbox = "dropbox";

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param string $consumerKey
     * @param string $consumerSecret
     * @param string $oauthToken
     * @param string $oauthTokenSecret
     * @param string $allowedRootId
     */
    public function __construct(String $consumerKey, String $consumerSecret, String $oauthToken, String $oauthTokenSecret, String $allowedRootId) {
        $this->consumerKey = $consumerKey;
        $this->consumerSecret = $consumerSecret;
        $this->oauthToken = $oauthToken;
        $this->oauthTokenSecret = $oauthTokenSecret;
        $this->allowedRootId = $allowedRootId;
    }
```

In my Controller:

```
class SmugmugController extends Controller {

    private $smugmugService;

    public function __construct(SmugmugService $smugmugService) {
        $this->smugmugService = $smugmugService;
    }
```

And when I try to call a route from my controller, I have this error:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Services\SmugmugService": argument
>   "$consumerKey" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "string", you
>   should configure its value explicitly.

I know that I call a controller with an injected service, who himself have injected parameters (is it the problem ?). Any help ?

Comment: You want to stop using service ids like smugmug_controller.  Use the fully qualified class name instead.  In fact if you replace the id with the class name then you can remove the class attribute.  And anytime you look at an example, always make sure it is for S4 with autowire.  It's all in the docs.

Comment: Dammit, it works with the full path, thanks ! Got mixed up in the answers I found..

Comment: @Cerad your comment should be an answer to this topic which can be accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Cerad answer:

You want to stop using service ids like smugmug_controller. Use the fully qualified class name instead. In fact if you replace the id with the class name then you can remove the class attribute. And anytime you look at an example, always make sure it is for S4 with autowire. It's all in the docs.

Comment: An example of what fixed it, and/or a link to the docs would be nice. The docs are vast and most people will have already searched and not found the answer. It's nice to hae the actual answer here.